# How do I get the c code of a nim program?

Tags: gcc, nim-lang

I followed the docs and compiled with `nim compileToC helloworld.nim`
 but it just spit out an executable. How can I see the intermediate C representation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## 2019 Update (Nim 0.19.2)

The default nimcache directory has changed from the current working directory to:

- `$HOME/.cache/nim/<project_name>` for Linux and MacOS
- `$HOME/nimcache/<project_name>` for Windows

See the relevant [nim compiler documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html#compiler-usage-generated-c-code-directory) article for details.

Answer (score 16):

`nim -c -d:release c helloworld.nim` just creates the C files in `nimcache`, without compiling and linking them. `-d:release` makes the code easier to read.

Comment: and `nimcache` location depends on OS, on my system the C files ended up under  `~/.cache/nim/`, in a directory named after each nim source file, with suffix `_d` or `_r`, presumably for "debug" and "release". You can control this with `--nimcache:...` command line switch.

Answer (score 3):

Solved: When you compile a nim program a `nimcache` directory is automatically generated in the same directory that contains the c code.

Comment: Not for a while, it seems. Nothing is generated in the working directory in 0.19.